# Problems with Capacitor Share Incorrect URL Scheme

Tags: reactjs, capacitor, url-scheme

I am encountering issues with Capacitor Share on mobile devices in my Ionic/Capacitor application. The problems are as follows:

URL Scheme Issue:
When I use window.location.href as the URL parameter for Capacitor.Share.share, the generated URL has a scheme like `capacitor://` instead of the expected `https://.` Is there a way to configure Capacitor to use the correct default URL scheme or a workaround to ensure the correct scheme?

Only solution I see for now it's do it manually like `https://' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname`

Code sample:

```
import { Share } from '@capacitor/share'
    
shareData({ title: document.title, url: window.location.href })
    
const shareData = async (data) => {
  try {
    await Share.share(data)
  } catch (error) {
        ...
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure Capacitor to use the correct default URL scheme or a workaround to ensure the correct scheme?

No, this is not possible on iOS. Yes, you can configure the local scheme on iOS in Capacitor (see [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config)). But `http` and `https` are not allowed according to the [Apple Developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/2875766-seturlschemehandler).